# How to trim a Base-64 encoded string?

Tags: php, base64

I'm not much of a PHP expert. I'm encoding a URL with `base64_encode`.
I get quite a long encoded string with a lot of weird characters exactly as I want it to be. 
Is there a way to trim this long line of characters to let's say 10 or 15 chars, so I can decode it later again?

I know there is `trim()` but that does not exactly what I want. I want a long encoded string to be rather short and later I want to decode it again.

Any ideas?

Comment: each of those characters represents part of the data, if you remove them you wont be able to decode it as some of the data will be missing.

Comment: Base-64 is an encoding and not an encryption.

Comment: Another URL shortening service? The usual approach is to create a database where you store your own ID along with the URL. That way your tokens/IDs/shortstrings can be whatever length you choose.

Comment: ok, doesn't matter if i use base64 or mycrypt encryption. i'm actually using mycrypt with a bit of base64 and trim in a function. I'm encrypting and decrypting later. That works fine! I'm encrpting for instance a url like http://www.google.com/imgages/whatever/flower.jpg … and than some 38udsf8z3r2… comes out. I'm passing this with my url into bit.ly Url Shortener. : http://www.mydomain.com#38udsf8z3r2 but somehow bitly doesn't support that. the encrypted hash at the end gets truncated???

Comment: @mathi in your example, it probably gets truncated because of the Hash: `#` what's the point of having that in the URL?

Comment: @mathi Sounds like a restriction in bit.ly. How long are your resulting URLs? And why are you doing all this? :)

Comment: I think the reason why this is not working is because bit.ly probably truncates to long hash-tags! I'll have to find another way!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible to "shorten" any string without losing some data.

- If you want to **physically shorten** an encoded string (with the end result being only part of that string), apply `substr()` but *not* on the encoded version: You need to decode it first, then re-encode the shortened version.
- Another option is to **compress** a string. This *may* shorten it somewhat: Look into [gzcompress()](http://php.net/gzcompress). Your mileage may vary, though: the compression rate will depend on what kind of data you have. With small input strings, the result can even be larger than the original.
- If you want to **reuse a variable in a multi-page process**, and don't want to transport it through a link or a form, consider generating a short random key, and storing the data in the user's session:

  ```
  $_SESSION[$randomKey] = "lllloooooooooooong data here";
  ```

  You could pass on the random key, and always access the "long" data using `$_SESSION[$randomKey]`. You need to have a [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) initialized for this.